# Problem rendering Hugo Lithium theme (blogdown), "Acess denied"

Tags: r, r-markdown, knitr, hugo, blogdown

I am trying to update a website using **blogdown**. However, the rendering fails. The website repo is in [this link](https://github.com/Jaimemosg/EstadisticaDescriptiva)

When I run `blogdown:::serve_site()`, I get the following error:

```
Start building sites â€¦ 
ERROR 2020/10/07 15:19:06 open C:\Users\jaime\Documents\R\EstadisticaDescriptiva\public\2020\10\03\estadÃ­stica-descriptiva-ejercicio\index.html: Access is denied.
ERROR 2020/10/07 15:19:06 open C:\Users\jaime\Documents\R\EstadisticaDescriptiva\public\index.html: Access is denied.
ERROR 2020/10/07 15:19:06 open C:\Users\jaime\Documents\R\EstadisticaDescriptiva\public\post\index.html: Access is denied.
ERROR 2020/10/07 15:19:06 open C:\Users\jaime\Documents\R\EstadisticaDescriptiva\public\categories\index.html: Access is denied.
Total in 366 ms
Error: Error building site: failed to render pages: open C:\Users\jaime\Documents\R\EstadisticaDescriptiva\public\about\index.html: Access is denied.
Start building sites â€¦ 
ERROR 2020/10/07 15:19:07 open C:\Users\jaime\Documents\R\EstadisticaDescriptiva\public\2020\10\03\estadÃ­stica-descriptiva-ejercicio\index.html: Access is denied.
ERROR 2020/10/07 15:19:07 open C:\Users\jaime\Documents\R\EstadisticaDescriptiva\public\2020\02\10\estadÃ­stica-desciptiva-en-python\index.html: Access is denied.
ERROR 2020/10/07 15:19:07 open C:\Users\jaime\Documents\R\EstadisticaDescriptiva\public\post\index.html: Access is denied.
ERROR 2020/10/07 15:19:07 open C:\Users\jaime\Documents\R\EstadisticaDescriptiva\public\categories\index.html: Access is denied.
Total in 390 ms
Error: Error building site: failed to render pages: open C:\Users\jaime\Documents\R\EstadisticaDescriptiva\public\about\index.html: Access is denied.
El sistema no puede encontrar la ruta especificada.
Error in shell(cmd, mustWork = TRUE, intern = intern) : 
  '"C:\Users\jaime\AppData\Roaming\Hugo\hugo.exe" -b / -D -F -d "public" --themesDir themes -t hugo-lithium' execution failed with error code 1
```

---

I have tried to create a new website from the beginning, using `blogdown::new_site(theme = 'usjrutheiser/hugo-lithium-theme')`, but I get the following error:

```
Error in if (dir_exists(expdir)) if (theme_example) { : 
  argument is of length zero
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In download.file(url, output, ..., method = method) :
  cannot open URL 'https://github.com/usjrutheiser/hugo-lithium-theme/archive/master.tar.gz': HTTP status was '404 Not Found'
2: In download.file(url, output, ..., method = method) :
  cannot open URL 'https://github.com/usjrutheiser/hugo-lithium-theme/archive/master.tar.gz': HTTP status was '404 Not Found'
3: In download.file(url, output, ..., method = method) :
  cannot open URL 'https://github.com/usjrutheiser/hugo-lithium-theme/archive/master.tar.gz': HTTP status was '404 Not Found'
4: In utils::untar(zipfile, exdir = tmpdir) :
  ‘tar.exe -xf "2ff459957c97master.tar.gz" -C "2ff46b705392"’ returned error code 1
```

I render the site in an old PC with R 3.6.3, and it worked, but in my new PC (R 4.0.2), it does not.
Does anyone know what this "Access denied error" means?  How can these errors be fixed?

---

## Edit

I have used other repository for lithium theme, and I used RStudio for creating it

[image: NewProject]

However, I get the same issue

```
Congratulations! Your new Hugo site is created in C:\Users\jaime\Documents\R\EjemplosEstadÃ­stica.

Just a few more steps and you're ready to go:

1. Download a theme into the same-named folder.
   Choose a theme from https://themes.gohugo.io/ or
   create your own with the "hugo new theme <THEMENAME>" command.
2. Perhaps you want to add some content. You can add single files
   with "hugo new <SECTIONNAME>\<FILENAME>.<FORMAT>".
3. Start the built-in live server via "hugo server".

Visit https://gohugo.io/ for quickstart guide and full documentation.
trying URL 'https://github.com/yihui/hugo-lithium/archive/master.tar.gz'
downloaded 109 KB

processing 7 content files
Error: Failed to save file "C:\\Users\\jaime\\Documents\\R\\EjemplosEstadÃ­stica\\content\\post\\2016-12-30-hello-markdown.md":: open C:\Users\jaime\Documents\R\EjemplosEstadÃ­stica\content\post\2016-12-30-hello-markdown.md: Access is denied.
processing 7 content files
Error: Failed to save file "C:\\Users\\jaime\\Documents\\R\\EjemplosEstadÃ­stica\\content\\post\\2016-12-30-hello-markdown.md":: open C:\Users\jaime\Documents\R\EjemplosEstadÃ­stica\content\post\2016-12-30-hello-markdown.md: Access is denied.
processing 7 content files
Error: Failed to save file "C:\\Users\\jaime\\Documents\\R\\EjemplosEstadÃ­stica\\content\\post\\2016-12-30-hello-markdown.md":: open C:\Users\jaime\Documents\R\EjemplosEstadÃ­stica\content\post\2016-12-30-hello-markdown.md: Access is denied.
Error in shell(cmd, mustWork = TRUE, intern = intern) : 
  '"C:\Users\jaime\AppData\Roaming\Hugo\hugo.exe" convert toYAML --unsafe' execution failed with error code 65535
```

Comment: It looks like the links simply do not work anymore. If you try one of the URLs from the error message you'll get a 404 error.

Comment: Yes, but why does it works with other R version? Could  be it  a problem related with Hugo version?

Comment: It's indeed confusing, perhaps the data was retrieved from some other place. In the meantime perhaps you can give a try to this fork: https://github.com/yihui/hugo-lithium ?

Comment: Thanks @Knak, it did not work eather for me :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This kind of problem occurs because the antivirus and the firewall application (I did not tell you that I am using Windows 10). Prevoiusly, I disabled my antivirus software for a while, but it did not work.

The solution was to add an exception not olny for R and RStudio, but also for `hugo.exe`.

Best wishes.